# For loops in R to populate the columns in the dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to formulate 2 for loops in R. I need to populate 2 columns (ColA and ColB) in Iris with values "X" and "Y" respectively. but I am not able to execute this. Any help would be appreciates

```
input <- c("X","Y")
col_names <- c("ColA", "ColB")

for (i in col_names){
  for (j in input)
  iris[[i]] <- paste0(j)
}
```

Expected output

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  ColA   COlB
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    X     Y
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    X     Y
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    X     Y
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    X     Y
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    X     Y
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    X     Y
```

Comment: `iris$colA <- "X"; iris$colB <- "Y"`. You don't need for loops for this.

Comment: I agree. But Can we not do this in loop ? Because the values are dynamic here. It keeps changing

Comment: What do you mean the "values are dynamic"? Could you illustrate with an MRE?

Comment: The values of COlA and COlB here are dynamic and not just "X" and "Y" all time. Makes sense :)

Comment: Aside from the comments above (you don't need a for loop for the problem as currently stated), `paste0()` is used to concatenate values, so it's not really what you want here.

Comment: You're also iterating over the input for each column, so you "paste" "X" then "Y" into "ColA", and then do the same for "ColB". Hence both end up with "Y" as the values.

Comment: I am also unable to understand why you need a loop here?  Even, the answer you have marked as correct can be done without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
myn <- 4
input <- sample(LETTERS, myn)
colnames <- paste0("Col", sample(LETTERS, myn))

if(length(input) == length(colnames)){
  for(i in 1:length(input)){
    
    iris$newcol <- input[i]
    names(iris)[ncol(iris)] <- colnames[i]
  }
} else{
  cat("length(input) != length(colnames)")
}

head(iris)

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species ColL ColM ColC ColY
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    T    J    E    I
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    T    J    E    I
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    T    J    E    I
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    T    J    E    I
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    T    J    E    I
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    T    J    E    I
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
input <- c("X","Y")
col_names <- c("ColA", "ColB")
df[col_names] <- as.list(input)
head(df)

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species ColA ColB
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    X    Y
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    X    Y
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    X    Y
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    X    Y
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    X    Y
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    X    Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. I was looking something in loops. Because the values are dynamic here :)

Comment: My answer works for dynamic values. I don't understand why a `for` loop would be **necessary**.

Comment: Nope. I see you are hardcoding values ("X" and "Y") here .

Comment: You can assign whatever you need to `new_val` though?

Comment: Well, I have edited my question :) So basically , the values takes in "col_names" and "input" as input and then executes

Comment: @user11740857 I don't really see why that would change my answer but I have edited the answer to use `col_names` and `input` from your question.